# Any way to make posts inherit properties/taxonomies through a single assigned taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, cms

I want to have a central "data" sheet that is regularly drawn upon for types of posts that are submitted.  Lets say I had a movie review site, but also want to let people post other info, like Trivia or some such.

So I would have 2 custom posts types (or perhaps one if I let Reviews just be handled in Posts).  I want both the review and the trivia to be search for by the movie title, the production company, the category the movie is in, etc.  I've been creating Taxonomies for each of these properties outside of the category.  What I've run into though is that every time a new review or piece of trivia is created for that movie, one would have to re-enter all that data.  I rather just have them choose the Movie title, and have the rest of that data inherited. So if they chose "Scream 4" for their review, it automatically inherits the "Horror" Category, "Wes Craven" as the director, and "Dimension Films" as the Studio without someone have to individually assign those taxonomies each time something is created.

Is there any way to do such a thing?

Comment: @Duiwel I'm not sure if this is what your going after, but a great resource (which helped me understand taxonomies) is exactly what you might be looking for. Heres the [link](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/06/04/using-custom-taxonomies-to-create-a-movie-database)

Comment: There are certainly ways to do this automatically when you save the post. Another way (thinking with the database here) is to use the `post_parent` field to link a review or trivia to a movie, just like attachments use this field to link to the post they are used on. If the reviews and trivias are even shorter you could maybe even (ab)use the comment structure for them, they are automatically linked to a post. These last two ways require some changes in how you query for them - do you have archive pages that list all reviews (not just movies) in one genre for example?

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for taking the time to comment, sorry I didn't get back to you sooner I was out of town for a few days.  For this particular project I realized I was going somewhat out of my way to make things more difficult and have since dumbed down my approach and managed to still get all the functionality out of the site.  With that being said, I know I have a project coming up that might need something a little more complex (and I was somewhat masking the particulars at the request of the friend/client I am doing this for) ...

Comment: So, I will definitely look into the post_parent field, and you said there were other ways to... you mentioned there are automatic ways to force categories to be inherited -- possible without linking them though the post_parent field, could you possibly elaborate?  I would be very interested in these methods.

Comment: If you had resolved this it would be great if you submitted your solution as an answer. Otherwise there is no reason to keep this question hovering around?

Comment: I was hoping Jan would expand on the "two other ways" he alluded too.

Comment: Oh and, no I hadn't "solved" it, I found a way to completely circumvent the issue without making things so complex - I'm still interested in Jan's other two ways though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest to use [Posts 2 Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/posts-to-posts/) plugin, see plugins page and [wiki](https://github.com/scribu/wp-posts-to-posts/wiki) for more information